# Worklight Access Disabled message in French

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I'm adding a multi language (French) to my Access Disabled feature on WL (6.2.0.1) console so I can let the users update to our new version of the app once it is submitted to the app store.

However, on the pop up message, how can I make the following in French, Is this can be controlled from WL?:

"System Error : Application Disabled" - "OK" - " Download new version"

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear to me where is "System Error" coming from, but you can change "Application Disabled" and "OK" in the corresponding localization bundle in the Xcode project.

Navigate to your-project\apps\your-app\native\Resources\Localizations.bundle

Note thought that there are already en.proj and fr.proj with the correctly translated strings.
The reason you see it in English is likely because the device is set to *English*.

You can change this in the device by going to: *Settings.app > General > Language & Region*, and change either *iPhone Language* or *Region* (one of them, don't remember right now).

Comment: Actually my device is in French and that's why I see the French message. However, just to get this clear, I need also to add localization for my request in the Xcode project!?

Comment: I don't understand. These files are already part of your generated Xcode project. If the device locale is in French, the app should use the correct localization file that contains the button labels in French (for "OK" and "Application Disabled"

Comment: Sorry for my Question. Looks like the developer has set in in the initOptions.js as the following and I didn't notice that. I will ask them to add the translation in our project : onErrorRemoteDisableDenial : function (message, downloadLink) {
  WL.SimpleDialog.show(
    "System Error: Application Disabled",
    message,
    [{text: "OK", handler: function() {WL.App.close();}},
     {text: "Download new version", handler: function() {WL.App.openURL(downloadLink, "_blank");}}]
  );
 },